# How to calculate the power dissipation of a receiver and a driver?

Tags: power, driver, receiver

I'm using the [AM26LV32E](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/am26lv32e.pdf?ts=1593600727912&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FAM26LV32E) receiver and the [AM26LV31E](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/am26lv31e.pdf?ts=1593600774935) driver and need to calculate how much power is dissipated on them (max).

I've been told I can calculate this using:

(1) For receiver: `Pd = Icc(max)*Vcc(max) + #ofCH*[Vol*Io+[(Vcc-Voh)*Ioh]`

(2) For driver: `Pd = Icc(max)*Vcc(max) + #ofCH*[Io(Vcc-Vod)]`

Two questions:

1. Are these formulas correct?
2. Is it possible that for the receiver, Vol should be Vil (and Voh = Vih)?

Comment: Does no one know?